# Create a temp table with data range using startdate and enddate from different records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I've got to write a command in Crystal Reports which should create some sort of temporary table to be used on the report itself.

I basicaly need:

`VATDates`:

```
+------------+------------+----------+---------+
|  StartDate |   EndDate  |  VATCode |  Rate   |
+------------+------------+----------+---------+
| 01/12/2008 | 31/12/2009 |    GB001 |      15 |
| 01/01/2010 | 31/12/2011 |    GB001 |    17.5 |
| 01/01/2012 |GETDATE()+1 |    GB001 |     20  |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

What I have:

`VATDates`:

```
+------------+----------+---------+
|    Date    |  VATCode |   Rate  |
+------------+----------+---------+
| 01/12/2008 |    GB001 |      15 |
| 01/01/2010 |    GB001 |    17.5 |
| 01/01/2012 |    GB001 |     20  |
+---------------------------------+
```

How can I get something with the result of the 1st table from data I have on the 2nd in a SQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subselect to get EndDate.

```
select
    v1.StartDate,
    isnull((select top 1 v2.StartDate - 1 from VATDates as v2 where v2.StartDate > v1.StartDate order by v2.StartDate), '9999-12-31') as EndDate,
    v1.VATCode,
    v1.Rate 
from
    VATDates as v1
```

Comment: Hi Rhys, Yes that works! Although the last record should have today's date + 1 (or maybe more given that invoices can be raised for future payment) as end date for invoices raised since the startdate to fall into that date range. Does it make sense?

Comment: I've added a default for the final end date - change the actual value to suit but the year 9999 should cover most future dated invoices :)

Comment: I'm trying to put a where clause on that query but am getting data conversion error. as in joining the invoice table and comparing invoice date between startdate and enddate

Comment: Please post a new question with the SQL you have and the error you are getting.

Comment: Hi @Rhys Jones, in regards to this one again though - the last record i'm getting a random enddate rather than the 9999. 

3 records with same VATCode which have different start dates:
V1 start 01.12.2008 ends 31.09.2009 20%
V2 start 01.01.2010 ends 03.01.2011 17%
V3 start 04.01.2011 ends 28.02.2014 20% > this last one should have end date 9999 but doesn't?! .. on nevermind about the error, i got it :) .. aaand nevermind! got it:)